# How to identify objects that don't need new to be created?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, new-operator

Usually, an object needs to be created using:

```
Object object = new Object();
```

However, this isn't the case for the String class. 
Right now I'm using Firebase Database. Instead of using *new*, they use .*getInstance()*. So the question is, how can I know if I need to use *new* or not for creating an object?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By reading the relevant Javadoc?

Comment: Or by checking if there's a `getInstance` Method xD? Also, primitives like string, int, double etc. Are different and can't be used with a constructor

Comment: @Twometer String is not a primitive, it is a class.

Comment: @LucianoFalco Integer is a class as well... but they are assigned directly.

Comment: @Twometer Integer is not a primitive either.

Comment: @Twometer `Integer` is a class. `int` is primitive.

Comment: I think @Twometer is talking about autoboxing?

Comment: Well if you want to be that precise ok, I was just trying to help the OP

Comment: What prevent you from doing a new String(« »)?

Comment: If a `getInstance()` method is present then you are most probably facing a `Factory` (cf. `design patterns` - search the Web). Given a class or simply an API (and its doc) first read the documentation to identify such cases or see what's the class and an instance of that class does propose as methods.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 way in which you can instantiate a class.

1. `Using` the new keyword, by calling the public constructor: `new MyClsss()`.
2. `Without using` new keyword. This case indicates that we are using either the `Singleton` or the `Factory` pattern. In a Singleton pattern, the name of the class used to get the object is the same as that of the class of the object. For example, `Connection con = Connection.getInstance();` Therefore, in Firebase the pattern that is used is `Factory` pattern.

So, to actually know how to instantiate a class, first you need to read the Java documentation for that class. But for learning purposes, i strongly recommend you to read more about creating new objects in java and design paterns.

The `factory method pattern` is a way to encapsulate object creation in Java. Without a factory method, we would simply call the class's constructor directly, as mentioned above `MyClsss myClsss = new MyClsss();`. The constructors of the class are marked as private, so they cannot be called except from inside the class. The factory method is marked as `static` so that it can be called without creating an object of the class. So the object returned by the factory method is created basically inside that class.